# Tallying elements at index in a multidimensional array

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to go through a multidimensional array and take a tally of the elements at each index

If I have an array that looks like the following:

```
letter_array = [[A,C,D],[C,F,R,L],[A,F,Q],[B,F,D]]
```

How would I tally each element at its index?

I'm aiming for an end result along the lines of something like this:

Index 0 - A:2, C:1, B:1

Index 1 - C:1, F:3

Index 2 - D:2, R:1, Q:1

Index 3 - L:1

Thank you

Comment: Did you have a chance to check my answer>

Comment: If, it solves your problem. You can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way will be this:

```
import pandas as pd        
data = pd.DataFrame(letter_array)
dictionary = {}
for i in range(len(data)):
    dictionary[i] = data[i].value_counts().to_dict()

dictionary
{0: {'A': 2, 'C': 1, 'B': 1},
 1: {'F': 3, 'C': 1},
 2: {'D': 2, 'Q': 1, 'R': 1},
 3: {'L': 1}}
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!